# check for first of type element

Tags: jquery

i have a scenario where i need to check whether an element in the dom is first of type

here is the html

```
<dl class="accordion">
        <dt>Select Category</dt>
        <dd></dd>

        <dt>select product</dt>
        <dd></dd>
</dl>
```

here is the script

```
(function($) {
        jQuery('.accordion > dt').on('click', function() {
            $this = $(this);
            $target = $this.next(); 
            if (!$this.hasClass('accordion-active')) {
                $this.parent().children('dd').slideUp();
                jQuery('.accordion > dt').removeClass('accordion-active');
                $this.addClass('accordion-active');
                $target.addClass('active').slideDown();
            }    
            return false;
        });
```

i need to know here is that whether the clicked element is first of the type .
Is this possible to check that way
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery supports the [`:first-of-type` selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/) in both its query methods and in [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is).

So:

```
if ($this.is(":first-of-type")) {
    // ...
}
```

Example:

```js
$("dt, dd").on("click", function() {
  console.log(
    ($(this).is(":first-of-type") ? "IS" : "Is NOT") +
    " the first of its type (" + this.tagName + ")"
  );
});
```

```html
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt>Select Category</dt>
  <dd>category data</dd>

  <dt>select product</dt>
  <dd>product data</dd>
</dl>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all dt elements and then use `.index()` to find index of current element in returned set. if it is `0` then that element is the first-of-type in complete DOM:

```
if($('dt').index($(this)) == 0){
   //code for first-of-type dt 
}
```